# Elasticsearch terms with spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of users with their interests in ElasticSearch:

Here's the mapping I have:

```
      mappings: {
        users: {
          properties: {
            username: {
              type: 'text',
              analyzer: 'autocomplete',
              search_analyzer: 'autocomplete'
            },
            interests: {
              type: 'text'
            },
            locations: {
              type: 'text'
            },
            roles: {
              type: 'text'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      settings: {
        analysis: {
          analyzer: {
            autocomplete: {
              type: 'custom',
              tokenizer: 'autocomplete',
              filter: ['lowercase']
            }
          },
          tokenizer: {
            autocomplete: {
              type: 'edge_ngram',
              min_gram: 3,
              max_gram: 10,
              token_chars: [
                'letter', 'digit'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Here's an example document:

```
  {
   "_index": "users",
   "_type": "users",
   "_id": "4",
   "_score": 1.0,
   "_source": {
     "username": null,
     "interests": [
       "live events"
     ],
     "locations": [
       "abington",
       "connecticut"
     ],
     "roles": [

     ]
   }
 }
```

Now when I search for:

```
{
  terms: ["live events"]
}
```

I get no results. I checked and it turns out that if the term contains a `space` then this happens. My guess was that terms looks for exact matches, but I am unable to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Interests field being of `type:text`, causes the original text to be saved as: ["live", "events"]. If you had indexed "live events" in the field it would have stored it as the above 2 separate tokens. When you use term query, it tries to directly match "live events". You need `match` query here. `Match` will ensure that your query goes through the same analysis phase as was used to store the documents.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena I need to limit the interest as an array as input, and hence match won't work. Any ways I can make this work without duplicating keywords?

Comment: Same issue but I'm looking for results for:
{
  terms: ["live events", "something", "else"]
}

any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `term/terms` query only for keyword datatype. In your case you are querying against a field with a `text datatype`,as written in your mapping:

```
    interests: {
      type: 'text'
    }
```

In this case you have to use the match query, instead, so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "interests" : "live events"
        }
    }
}
```